# on fetch collection is getting zero in backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

edit method

```
editCollection: (event) ->
  @collection = new BackboneDemo.Collections.Backbonescripts()
  @collection.url = "/demos/#{event.target.id}/test"
  @collection.fetch()
  @collection.on('sync', @selectCheckbox(event), this)

selectCheckbox: (event) ->
  console.info @collection.length
  @collection.each (test) ->
  $('#'+event.target.id+'.test #'+test.get('id')+'.test_checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

i even tried to use the reset and on success of the fetch...but length is zero

i know that back bone is lazy loading

How to use wait till fetch is completed......?

Answer (score 0):

Replace those lines on:

```
editCollection: (event) =>
  . . .
selectCheckbox: (event) =>
  . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function call:

```
@collection.on('sync', @selectCheckbox(event), this)
# ---------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're calling `@selectCheckbox` and passing its return vale to `@collection.on` as though you said this:

```
x = @selectCheckbox(event)
@collection.on('sync', x, this)
```

so you're calling `@selectCheckbox` before the `'sync'` event happens. I think you want to say this:

```
@collection.on('sync', @selectCheckbox, @)
# ---------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Now just a function reference
```

Also, you should be careful of your indentation inside `selectCheckbox` or your `@collection.each` will be iterating with an empty function:

```
selectCheckbox: (event) ->
  console.info @collection.length
  @collection.each (test) ->
    $("##{event.target.id}.test ##{test.get('id')}.test_checkbox").prop('checked', true)
```